# How to Export HTML Table (shown with PHP from MySQL) while running the file from Server?

Tags: php, excel, file, permissions, extract

I have written Codes on a .PHP file to Export a Table in Excel Format.

When I run the .PHP file from Localhost (with XAMPP) the code works properly. A Excel file extracts as .XLS.

But, when I am putting this .PHP file on Server, .XLS file is being extracted, but with no value inside it.

I suspect, possibly it is a problem of File Permission; but I am not sure.

I am also not sure that what mode (CHMOD 777 or something else) should I assign to that specific files.

Please help me to solve this problem.

The code goes below:

```
<head>
<?php
        $str='';
        $fileName = 'report'.date("Y-m-d").".xls";
        $f=@fopen("download/excel/".$fileName,"w+");
?>
</head>

<body>
$str.="<table>MY TABLE CODES INSIDE THIS</table>";

    @fwrite($f,$str);
    @fclose($f);
</body>
```

Comment: Don't suspect, debug. We can't help without any solid information (like code responsible for writing / reading this file) and you are not providing any here. See [php tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) especially `I have a typical "does not work" problem.` section.

Comment: Please solve my problem, it is very very urgent in fact...

Comment: We are here to help you solve your problem, not do it for you. If it is urgent hire a developer to fix it for you.

Comment: I am trying hard, but I am not understanding. I am just requesting for some guideline, nothing else. It is not any official work :( Sorry if my expression is wrong.

Comment: Have you seen the link I provided in first comment?

Comment: I found the problem :-/ I forgot to give permission to the directory "excel". Still thanks dev-null-dweller for viewing my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You just can't save a `html` written `table` into an Excel file and expect it to open in Excel and show you the same table.

Comment: Actually, yes, you can, it works perfectly. Just save the HTML file as .xls and Excel will pick it up.